# Deleting only "strings" in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying to make a function that removes only the "strings" from the array. I'm looking to only have the numbers left. I've already accomplished this by adding numbers only to a newArray, and I was looking into the splice method but could not figure out how to write it. As you see in code delete works, but returns undefined in its spot.

```
function numbersOnly(arr){

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(typeof arr[i] === "string"){
        delete arr[i];
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
 }
numbersOnly([1, "apple", -3, "orange", 0.5, 22, "hello", 6])
```

returns [1, undefined, -3, undefined, 0.5, 22, undefined, 6]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: You could just push the non-string types into a new array and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you delete sth in an array, there stays an empty space which is *undefined*. You need to *shift* the array, so replace

```
 delete arr[i];
```

with

```
arr=arr.slice(0,i).concat(arr.slice(i+1));
i--;
```

or using splice:

```
arr.splice(i,1);
i--;//dont jump over this index
```

or using a for loop:

```
for(var b=i;b<arr.length-1;b++){
  arr[b]=arr[b+1];
}
arr.length-=1;
i--;
```

---

Alternatively you could filter:

```
arr.filter(el=>typeof el==="number");//numbers only
//or
arr.filter(el=>typeof el!=="string");//not stringd
```

Comment: If you use `splice` or similar, all the indexes shift, so `i` has the wrong value afterwards.

Comment: @Jonas w-That's what I was looking for! Thanks

Comment: @robert amato youre welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [1, "apple", -3, "orange", 0.5, 22, "hello", 6];
var out = arr.filter(function(f) { return typeof(f) !== 'string';});
console.log( out );
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use [array.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead of delete, which is for properties.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a go another way around

```
function numbersOnly(arr){
let numbers = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(typeof arr[i] === "number"){
    numbers.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
console.log(numbers);
```

}

Comment: Why are you mixing `let` and `var`?

Comment: I just copied his code and added my stuff , I am not using var at all

Answer (score 0):

If the array's cell contains a number and that number yields true for `if Number()`. Then that value will be added to a secondary array and returned.

```js
  function numbersOnly(arr){ 

      var numbersarr = [];
      var i;
      var k = 0;
      for (i=0; i< arr.length ;i++) {
    
      if (  Number(arr[i])   ) {
           
            numbersarr[k++] = arr[i];
         }
     }
      
      console.log(numbersarr);
      return numbersarr;
     }

    var strarr = [1, "apple", -3, "orange", 0.5,
                  22, "hello", 6 , "car", "123" , 
                  "zoo", "456"];
        
    numbersOnly(strarr);    
    numbersOnly(["foo","bar", "something"]);
```

And this is how your output will be:

```
  [1, -3, 0.5, 22, 6, "123", "456"]
```

Comment: Did you even try this? It should remove all elements (they're all strings) but it doesn't. Also try with an input of `[ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]`.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I tried it. I ran the code first, then I brought it here. I updated my answer to show the output.

Comment: Your code left `"123"` and `"456"` in the array even though they're strings. This is wrong. (Also, you should really try running it on `[ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]`.)

Comment: @melpomene He did not specify in his requirement that "123" is not considered a number.  and 123  a number.

Comment: Javascript itself specifies that `"123"` is a string (and `123` is a number). But even if you ignore that, `numbersOnly([ "foo", "bar", "baz" ])` outputs `[ "bar" ]`. Surely you don't think that `"bar"` is considered a number?

Comment: @melpomene look, I hear you, I know what you mean. But he wanted to remove the cells with alphabets in them.

Comment: `numbersOnly(["foo", "bar", "baz"])` outputs `["bar"]`. It should output `[]`. Your code is broken.

Comment: @melpomene You are correct. that got taken care of.

Comment: @melpomene on a side note.  Number(arr[i]) returns "123" as a number. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

use `.splice(index, count)`

```js
function numbersOnly(arr) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(typeof arr[i] === "string") {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
numbersOnly([1, "apple", -3, "orange", 0.5, 22, "hello", 6]);
```

Comment: Breaks if there are multiple strings in a row in the input array.

Comment: `Breaks`?  I dont understand what you're talking

Comment: Try running your code on `[ "foo", "bar", "baz" ]`. What do you expect the result to be? What do you actually get?